# linux rename file names recursively

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, mv

I need to recursively rename **bash-sdl2-compile.sh** to **compile.sh**
Attempts to use 'rename' fail, apparently a security feature doesn't allow the 'bash' word i.e.

```
find ./ -name "bash-sdl2-compile.sh" -print0 | xargs -0 rename "bash-sdl2-compile.sh" "bash-sdl2-compile/compile"
```

*error message: Bareword "bash" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).
xargs: rename: exited with status 255; aborting*

How can I recursively rename linux files?

```
    dir1
       |_project1
                |_ bash-sdl2-compile.sh
    dir2
       |_project2
                |_ bash-sdl2-compile.sh
    dir3
       |_project3
                |_ bash-sdl2-compile.sh
  . . .
```

So, rename each "bash-sdl2-compile.sh" to just "compile.sh"

Comment: That looks like all files will end up with just one name, does it not?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your directory before and after the move please?

Comment: I have 20 sub-directories each with a file named **"bash-sdl2-compile.sh"** and I need to change it to **"compile.sh"** The code I am showing was posted on "Stack server"

Comment: @jwzumwalt : Your error message looks to me as if it was issued by a Perl program. Aside from this, you don't have a bareword _bash_ in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `xargs`, `find` is enough:

```
find . -name bash-sdl2-compile.sh -execdir mv -i {} compile.sh ";"
```

(make a backup of your whole tree before trying this)

Comment: This does not work, has errors,  **find . -name bash-sdl2-compile.sh -execdir mv {} bash-sdl2-compile/compile ";"**  output:mv: cannot move './bash-sdl2-compile.sh' to 'bash-sdl2-compile/compile': No such file or directory

Comment: If you really want to put all `bash-sdl2-compile.sh` files in one single directory, thus overwriting all the files by the last one found, then change `-execdir` with `-exec`. I'm not sure this is really what you want (hence my answer) and you should backup your files first.

Comment: I am trying to recursively move down dirs and find "file1" and rename to "file2" in its original directories.

Comment: Please amend your question and explain what you want. Especially: what is file2? Is it bash-sdl2-compile/compile? Or bash-sdl2-compile/compile/bash-sdl2-compile.sh? Or something else? Don't just answer to me, please edit your question so that it's clear for everyone.